# Optimizing the algorithm for brute force numbers in the problem

Tags: python, algorithm

How many pairs `(i, j)` exist such that `1 <= i <= j <= n`, `j - i <= a`?
`'n'` and `'a'` input numbers.

The problem is my algorithm is too slow when increasing 'n' or 'a'.
I cannot think of a correct algorithm.
Execution time must be less than 10 seconds.

Tests:

- n = 3
  a = 1
  Number of pairs = 5
- n = 5
  a = 4
  Number of pairs = 15
- n = 10
  a = 5
  Number of pairs = 45
- n = 100
  a = 0
  Number of pairs = 100
- n = 1000000
  a = 333333
  Number of pairs = 277778388889
- n = 100000
  a = 555555
  Number of pairs = 5000050000
- n = 1000000
  a = 1000000
  Number of pairs = 500000500000
- n = 998999
  a = 400000
  Number of pairs = 319600398999
- n = 898982
  a = 40000
  Number of pairs = 35160158982

```
n, a = input().split()

i = 1
j = 1

answer = 0

while True:
    if n >= j:
        if a >= (j-i):
            answer += 1

            j += 1

        else:
            i += 1
            j = i

            if j > n:
                break

    else:
        i += 1
        j = i

        if j > n:
            break

print(answer)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can derive a direct formula to solve this problem.

```
ans = ((a+1)*a)/2 + (a+1) + (a+1)*(n-a-1)
```

Thus the time complexity is `O(1)`. This is the fastest way to solve this problem.

Derivation:

The first `a` number can have pairs of `(a+1)C2 + (a+1)`.
Every additional number has 'a+1' options to pair with. So, therefore, there are `n-a-1` number remaining and have `(a+1)` options, `(a+1)*(n-a-1)`

Therefore the final answer is  `(a+1)C2 + (a+1) + (a+1)*(n-a-1)` implies `((a+1)*a)/2 + (a+1) + (a+1)*(n-a-1)`.

Comment: Nice, I was in the process of deriving a closed-form formula from my answer when I saw how your approach was able to get the formula with much less fuss.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a quadratic algorithm but you should be able to get it to linear (or perhaps even better).

The main problem is to determine how many pairs, given `i` and `j`. It is natural to split that off into a function.

A key point is that, for `i` fixed, the `j` which go with that `i` are in the range `i` to `min(n,i+a)`. This is since `j-i <= a` is equivalent to `j <= i+a`.

There are `min(n,i+a) - i + 1` valid `j` for a given `i`. This leads to:

```
def count_pairs(n,a):
    return sum(min(n,i+a) - i + 1 for i in range(1,n+1))
```

`count_pairs(898982,40000)` evaluates to `35160158982` in about a second. If that is still to slow, do some more mathematical analysis.

Comment: Oh,that explains it. Impressive.

Comment: @AnnZen   `n,a` would actually be a bit more idiomatic (more like the `range()` function) and mesh better with OP's code, so I will tweak it. Thanks for noticing that my parameter order was slightly unnatural

Comment: You can improve its efficiency by eliminating the evaluation of `+1` in each iteration: `return sum(min(n,i+a) - i for i in range(2,n+2))`

Comment: And by evaluating the `-i` inside the `min` function: `return sum(min(n-i,a) for i in range(2,n+2))`

Comment: @AnnZen Doubtless there are tweaks, but compared with the accepted answer it would be like rearranging deck furniture on the Titanic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improvement:

```
n, a = map(int, input().split())

i = 1
j = 1

answer = 0

while True:
    if n >= j <= a + i:
        answer += 1
        j += 1
        continue
    i = j = i + 1
    if j > n:
        break
        
print(answer)
```

Comment: @selfAlex Updated. `continue` is faster then `else`.